# Rails 7: Could not find generator 'stimulus'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, stimulusjs

I have recently upgraded our application to Rails 7 and want to use Stimulus. I understand that with Rails 7 its comes by default.

I am trying to execute `rails generate stimulus Downloader` but this results in Could not find generator 'stimulus'.

Are there any additional steps i need to perform to use Stimulus?

Any help here would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes with *rails 7* in a form of a gem `stimulus-rails`:
*https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails#installing-with-installer*

```rb
bundle add stimulus-rails
bin/rails stimulus:install
```

Everything else also comes in a gem `importmap-rails`, `jsbundling-rails`, `cssbundling-rails`, `turbo-rails`, `tailwindcss-rails` - and has an install task which *rails* runs for you when making a new app with `rails new`. For existing apps you have to follow install instructions for each gem.

Comment: thanks Alex, this worked. However on a separate issue i have followed the instructions mentioned on stimulus-rails but the connect method of my controller or greet does not get called. nothing in the console as well (https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/). any ideas?

Comment: @opensource-developer that'll depend on your javascript setup. maybe you need to run `bin/dev`. there is a debug option in `app/javascript/controllers/application.js` - but that's only useful if Stimulus is actually loading on the page. type `Stimulus` in browser console, you should see a stimulus Application instance.

Comment: i have created  a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76677979/rails-7-stimulus-not-working-no-errors-in-console

Comment: btw when i type `Stimulus` in browser console i see a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Stimulus`