# Rails 7: Stimulus not working, no errors in console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I am following the instructions on https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/ and executed

```
Add the stimulus-rails gem to your Gemfile: gem 'stimulus-rails'
Run ./bin/bundle install.
Run ./bin/rails stimulus:install
```

below is the `app/javascripts/controller/application.js`

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = true
window.Stimulus   = application

Stimulus.handleError = (error, message, detail) => {
  console.warn(message, detail)
  ErrorTrackingSystem.captureException(error)
}

export { application }
console.log('helllo world');
```

below is the `app/javascripts/controller/hello_controller.js`

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects with data-controller="hello"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "name", "output" ]

  connect() {
    console.log('connected');
  }

  greet() {
    console.log('hello world!!');
    this.outputTarget.textContent = `Hello, ${this.nameTarget.value}!`
  }
}
```

below is the `app/javascripts/controller/index.js`

```
// This file is auto-generated by ./bin/rails stimulus:manifest:update
// Run that command whenever you add a new controller or create them with
// ./bin/rails generate stimulus controllerName

import { application } from "./application"

import HelloController from "./hello_controller"
application.register("hello", HelloController)
console.log('hellow');
```

here is the relevant view code in one of the index pages

```
<div data-controller="hello">
  <input data-hello-target="name" type="text">

  <button data-action="click->hello#greet">Greet</button>

  <span data-hello-target="output"></span>

</div>
```

After adding text and clicking greet button nothing happens, nothing in the browser console, no errors or warnings.

any help here would be great, Thanks.

Comment: `app/javascripts` => `app/javascript`. is there `import "./controllers` in `app/javascript/application.js`. you're not using importmaps, so `bin/dev` to run and compile javascript. jsbundling should output into `app/assets/builds` which should be in `manifest.js` and then in your layout `javascript_include_tag "application"`. i've seen too many people precompile so run `rails assets:clobber` if you did.

Comment: if you still have `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` it might override the other compiled `application.js`

Comment: thanks Alex, sorry for the typo its `app/javascript` indeed. I added the `import "./controllers" as well.  I do have `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` where all of the app js reside. is it possible to have both in combination working. I ran `bin/webpack-dev-server` and also `rails assets:clobber` but still same error, when i run `Stimulus` on browser console i see `can't find variable`

Comment: webpacker uses packs. so `app/javascript/packs/application.js` should have the `import "../controllers"`. you should be fine with `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, webpacker doesn't affect it. i assume you have `javascript_pack_tag "application"` somewhere in the layout.

Comment: If the instructions don't work or are outdated, you should [open an issue](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails/issues) on GitHub.

Comment: thanks Alex, i think i am getting closer but i have tried various imports but i end up getting "ERROR in ./app/javascript/controllers/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './controllers'" i have tried `import '../controllers'`  & `import './controllers'` & `const controllers = require.context('../controllers', true, /\.js$/);
controllers.keys().forEach(controllers);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from webpacker wasn't that bad, so you might as well spend time on moving to something else than fixing all these issues.

But in case you want to compare your set up, here what I've figured out:

```bash
# Rails 7.0.6
nvm use 16
rails new install_nojs -J
cd install_nojs
bundle add webpacker stimulus-rails
rails webpacker:install
rails stimulus:install
rails g controller Home index
yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object --dev
```

```bash
bin/webpack-dev-server
bin/rails s
```

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')

import "../controllers"
```

```rb
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

<%= javascript_pack_tag "application" %>
```

Note that packages were renamed with `@hotwired` prefix at some point:

```js
// import { Controller } from "stimulus"           // nay
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"    // yay

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "name", "output" ]
  greet() {
    this.outputTarget.textContent = `Hello, ${this.nameTarget.value}!`
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- app/views/home/index.html.erb -->
<div data-controller="hello">
  <input data-hello-target="name" type="text">
  <button data-action="click->hello#greet">Greet</button>
  <span data-hello-target="output"></span>
</div>
```

```
open http://localhost:3000/home/index
```

This works.